# Java Swing - hight CPU usage

Tags: java, performance, swing, paint, cpu-usage

## Java Swing - hight CPU usage

I have two component classes which are override the `public void paint(Graphics g)` method.
Classes:

```java
    public abstract class DragItemComp extends JPanel {
        private MouseAdapter butListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                ...
                possibleList = new JFrame();
                possibleList.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                possibleList.setType(Type.UTILITY);
                ...
                setPreferredSize(neededSize);
            }
        };
        public JFrame possibleList;
        public DragItemComp() {
            setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            createComps();
            addMouseListener(butListener);
            f = new Font(getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, 14);
        }
        public void createComps(){
            removeAll();
            int h = 0;
            for (ConnectPoint connectPoint : blueVisible) {
                connectPoint.setLocation(0, h);
                h += connectPoint.getHeight()+6; 
            }
        }
        public void onMove(){
            if(possibleList == null || !possibleList.isVisible())
                return;
            
            //calculating stuff
            possibleList.setLocation(newPoint);
            possibleList.repaint();
            System.gc();
            //updating fields
        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            //...;
            g.setFont(new Font(...));
            //...
            setPreferredSize(neededSize);
            System.gc();
        }
        public class ConnectPoint extends JPanel{
            private Font f; 
            public ConnectPoint(String text,Runnable onClick)
            {
                ...
                setSize(text.length()*getFont().getSize()+20, 15);
                addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Click");
                        new Thread(onClick).start();
                        DragItemComp.this.redPossible.remove(this);
                        DragItemComp.this.redVisible.add(ConnectPoint.this);
                    }
                });
                //adding key listener
            }
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                if(out)
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillOval(0, 0, 10, 10);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.setFont(f);
                g.drawString(text, 15, 11);
            }
            //interface method implementations cut out
        }
    }
```

I know this is a lot of code and a am sorry for it (edit: reduced code by a large chunk).
I have a suspicion that this class could cause the issue

```
public class JavaScriptDropFileComponent extends JPanel {
    //fields
    public JavaScriptDropFileComponent() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        placeFrame = new JFrame();
        //...
        new Thread(()->{
            while(isVisible()){
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                if(nextPlace == null || !tryIt.isVisible()){
                    continue;
                }
                if(some_condition) {
                    if(placeFrame.isVisible())
                        placeFrame.setVisible(false);
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    if(!placeFrame.isVisible())
                        placeFrame.setVisible(true);
                }
                placeFrame.setLocation(/*some computet point (just a few multiplications*/);
                if(condition)
                    placeFrame.setSize(justSomrDimension);
            }
            
        }).start();
    }
}
```

For shortening I removed the getter/setter, imports, fields and non informative code.
(edit: I further removed code, and replaced some irrelevant conditions etc)

So why does it needs so much CPU and how can i change it?

Another interesting fact is that the CPU usage does not depends on the sleep time of the thread. I tried it with 100000, 1000, 10, 1 ms. it doesn't changed anything!

I [uploaded](http://www.mediafire.com/?3b60k77senpys) all classes you need to executed. -> DragTester.java is main class.
May you need to change the "package com.niton.**" decalration.
I updated the code for needing less CPU.

Comment: Look at it with a profiler, like YourKit

Comment: Please first isolate the problem in a [mcve] before posting a wall of code.

Comment: I said i am sorry for posting that much code.

Comment: I think this question is better-suited for CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - I am not ready to look at that much code - an [mcve] is necessary

Comment: but i dont know where's the problem so i dont know which code i can delete and which should stay there

Comment: You find out by either using a profiler or chopping out bits of code and finding the problem, but again this should be done before posting a wall of code.

Comment: @ochi: they (codereview) are going to request a decent MCVE as well, as is well within their right to do so.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels in complete agreement with you... that's too much code/time for anyone to get their heads wrapped around

Comment: Which code should i remove

Comment: @Niton: **AGAIN**, you will need to experiment and isolate the error. That's a lot of work, but it should be **your** work.

Comment: i will do it but i am scared to reserve information

Comment: ok i will try so

Comment: get rid of the `while (xxx.isVisible())` loop, it's bad and serves no purpose. That's not how event driven GUI's work, and instead you should use notification, not a while loop.

Comment: But it`s not normal that paint(Graphics g) needs so much CPU? or?

Comment: Thx for help. Should i close the question?

Comment: I would, then re-open it when / if you can post shorter runnable code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I am really happy that you tryed to help me.THX

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any Swing programming, but could the problem be related to calling setPreferredSize from within your paint method?

Comment: @MichaelKrause: good catch, that's always a bad idea. The paintComponent method should be for painting and painting only, and in no way should change the state of the object. Though I don't think that this will cause a direct problem, since there is no code following it to pack or revalidate the GUI. So likely components won't re-size.

Comment: Changing the state of the component inside `paint` is not a good idea, this can trigger new paint cycles which can consume more CPU cycles

Comment: Also - you're creating a new Font every time in your paint method.  You should create it once, cache it, and refer to the cached font reference from your paint method.

Comment: "i will do it but i am scared to [remove?] information"  ---  If you are new to this kind of programming, I strongly recommend that you **make a backup** of all your code before you start trying to create a MCVE --- either copy the file (or the whole directory tree) elsewhere, or archive it all in something like a .zip file.  If possible, your MCVE should be a new `.java` file (so you don't risk any of what you have now.  If this is part of a larger app and you really do have to change this file in-place, you'll need the backups to recover all the code you delete or comment out.

Comment: 70% might still be excessive in light of this, but keep in mind that's 70% of one of your eight cores.  Sometimes you'll see a process taking over 100% CPU if it's running on more than one core.  (At least that's how `top` reports it on Linux.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I mean I did not want you to lose information because I remove code. Translated from German with Google Translator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: Don't do more work than you absolutely have to from within your paint method.

At a quick glance, you are creating a new Font and calling setPreferredSize every time paint is called.

Create your Font once and cache it and refer to it from your paint method.

Also, call setPreferredSize outside of your paint method.